# Can we have a site for spider/insect identification?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

After seeing the various types of Stack Exchanges there are, I was thinking it would be nice to have a spider/insect identification one as well.

There have been a few times that I found a spider in my house and would like to know what kind of spider it was. The biggest benefit would be to know if this spider was poisonous or not. There are a couple of other sites that do this but they are not well organized and takes almost as long to find your spider on their site as it does my looking through all the "spider" images on Google. It would be nice to have a better organized community like we see here doing a site like this.

Comment: As the Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites (not help forums), meant to be searchable for later visitors who have the same question: how would one search such question? Also, there's [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for new proposals, but I give it little chance.

Comment: http://www.spiders.com.au/ http://www.termite.com.au/spider-identification.html  - you can look online, I doubt it would be popular  SE site idea over at area 51.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question has a scientific twist to it (i.e., "Does this insect's body morphology make it closely related to [this other insect]?") rather than "Hey, what's this bug?" then it would probably be okay on [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com).

See the following questions from the site's Meta for its position on identification questions:

- [Plant Identification Questions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/plant-identification-questions)
- [Species Identification Questions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/species-identification-questions)
- [Is it on-topic to ask for the identification of any living organism?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-for-the-identification-of-any-living-organism)

Otherwise, it is likely to be off-topic everywhere else, currently.

What you propose is not a good candidate for producing strong questions that follow the format of a Q + A site, and would not be likely to garner much support on its own, anyway.